# Can Visual Studio 2010 work with classic ASP include files?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, asp-classic

I'm testing VS 2010 with a classic ASP VBScript site I have to work on. It can auto complete and show reference for user functions. However it doesn't analyze 'include' files, so library functions won't be available for intellisense features like autocomplete, parameter reference, 'go to definition', etc.

Is it possible for VS 2010 to count the include chain in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no intellisense or design view integration support for SSI, as they're managed at webserver (iis) level by the approprate ISAPI.

Comment: oh, thanks for reminding, SSI is not a part of ASP so this question doesn't only apply to ASP, but is more generic. Well, that's too bad..